# Understanding $A^A$ in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ so what will be $A^A$?

What is the geometric interpretation for $A^A$?

Thanks

Comment: i deleted that tag.Thanks

Comment: But what does this have to do with linear algebra?

Comment: it's a notation from our course

Comment: Someone should probably take out the "in linear algebra" bit in the title.

Comment: I am fairly certain this was asked and answered more than once before on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A^B$ is frequently notation for the set of functions from $B$ to $A$.

So $\{1, 2, 3\}^{\{1, 2, 3\}}$ would be the set of functions from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to itself; so for example, if $f$ is a function defined by

$f(1) = 3$, $f(2) = 2$, $f(3) = 3$

then $f \in \{1, 2, 3\}^{\{1, 2, 3\}}$.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @ocean Gave an example in the post body.

Comment: Why isn't the 'empty' function a member of $A^B$? A function, as I understand it, is a relation, i.e. a subset of $A \times B$, such that $\forall (a,b) \ \in A \times B, aRb \wedge aRb' \implies b=b'$. The empty set is certainly a subset of $A \times B$ and it vacuously satisfies any $\forall$ statement. I know it can't be a member because I recall that the cardinality of $A^B$ is $|A|^{|B|}$ for finite sets, but I can't see how to make this work.

Comment: @DepeHb A member of $A^B$ not only has to be a function and a subset of $A\times B$, it has to have domain equal to $B$.  This means that every element of $B$ must be the first component of some element of your function. The only way for that to happen when the function has no elements is for $B$ to also have no elements. So, the empty set is in $A^B$ if and only if $B=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A = \{1,2,3\}$, then

$$A^A = \{f_i:\ i=1,\dots,3^3\},$$

where $f_k:\ A \to A$ and

\begin{align*}
f_{1}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{1}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{1}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{2}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{2}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{2}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{3}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{3}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{3}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{4}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{4}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{4}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{5}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{5}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{5}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{6}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{6}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{6}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{7}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{7}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{7}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{8}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{8}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{8}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{9}(1) &= 1, \quad &f_{9}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{9}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{10}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{10}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{10}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{11}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{11}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{11}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{12}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{12}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{12}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{13}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{13}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{13}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{14}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{14}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{14}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{15}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{15}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{15}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{16}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{16}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{16}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{17}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{17}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{17}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{18}(1) &= 2, \quad &f_{18}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{18}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{19}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{19}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{19}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{20}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{20}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{20}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{21}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{21}(2) &= 1, \quad &f_{21}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{22}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{22}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{22}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{23}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{23}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{23}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{24}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{24}(2) &= 2, \quad &f_{24}(3) &= 3, \\
f_{25}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{25}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{25}(3) &= 1, \\
f_{26}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{26}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{26}(3) &= 2, \\
f_{27}(1) &= 3, \quad &f_{27}(2) &= 3, \quad &f_{27}(3) &= 3. \\
\end{align*}

Since $A^A$ is a set, the order of $f_i$ is, of course, irrelevant.

Comment: Because my fingers tend to be quicker than my brain. I was far more focused on getting the "table" done in bash (too lazy to type it by hand). I've fixed it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is used for the set of functions from $A$ to $A$. It makes sense because each of the three elements of $A$ can be mapped to $1$ or $2$ or $3$ - so the number of functions turns out to be $3^3$.

$f(1)= 1, 2 \text { or } 3$

$f(2)= 1, 2 \text { or } 3$

$f(3)= 1, 2 \text { or } 3$

Answer (score 1):

Anothe famous example is when we write $2^X$.  Let $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$ in which $X$ is a set. Then the following relation $$\{(x,y)\in X\times \{0,1\}\mid y=1~~ \text{when}~~x\in A; ~y=0~~\text{when}~~x\notin A\}$$ is a function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$. This function is known as $\chi_A$