# Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $f:P(A)\rightarrow A^A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $f:P(A)\rightarrow A^A$ defined by $\forall a\in A:f(X)(a)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} a & : & a\in X \\
6-a & : & a\notin X  \end{array}\right.$

That's a follow question that i asked: [Understanding $A^A$ in set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457472/86739)

I still can't figure how they build $f$ can someone give me an example of 2 different sets that goes from $f$ to the same image?

Or enlighten me in some way.

Thanks

Comment: $f$ is a function. It doesn't have "elements" per se, except as pairs of values $(X,f(X))$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - i meant sets. thanks.

Comment: You meant what sets?

Comment: example of, say, 2 different sets from f to the same image

Answer (score 2):

$f$ takes as input a subset of $A$ (an element of $P(A)$).  It gives as output a function from $A$ to $A$.  That is, $f(X)$ is a function from $A$ to $A$.  To specify a function we need to say what it does on every input.

What the statement does is give a function from $A$ to $A$ (that depends on the input subset $X$).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a function that eats en element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$, and spits out a function from $A$ to $A$. So it accepts a subset of $A$, and returns a function whose domain and range are $A$.

For example, if we choose $X = \{1, 2\}$, and let $g = f(X)$, we see that

$g(1) = 1$

$g(2) = 2$

$g(3) = 6 - 3 = 3$

$g(4) = 6 - 4 = 2$

$g(5) = 6 - 5 = 1$

So $g$ is the function defined by these values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can understand the behavior of $f$ better by first understanding the "uncurried" version its definition. You can learn about currying [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). We define a function $g:\mathcal P(A)\times A\to A$ by saying that $g(S,a)$ is $a$ if $a\in S$ and it is $6-a$ if $a\not\in S$.

Now, keep $S$ the same and notice that $a\mapsto g(S,a)$ is a function $A\to A$. Since it is a parametrized by $S\in\mathcal P(A)$, we write $f(S)$ to refer to this function. But then, $f$ is function from $\mathcal P(A)$ to functions $A\to A$. You should certainly check that $f$ defined this way matches the given definition of $f$.

Comment: so can i say $f(x)=f(x)(1)+...+f(x)(5)?$